# Does each player need their own portal to play Skylanders?

Tags: skylanders

Does each kid need their own portal for WII to play Skylanders or can they use one? New to this game and I haven't read anything that says you need two portals. Please let me know if I need to buy another portal before giving the game as a gift. Thanks!

Comment: I know there are [different versions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skylanders#Games) of this game (Swap Force, Giants, etc).  The answer *might* depend on which game you are talking about.

Answer (score 3):

Only 1 portal is needed, two controllers though..

Comment: I can confirm this as my son owns Skylanders.